# phpldapadmin: login as "root" admin user with UID

Tags: login, openldap, uid, ldap

I have recently installed phpldapadmin on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Srv.

In the the `config.php` I've modified the following parameter in order to enable simple user login:

```
$servers->('login','bind_pass','secret');
```

and

```
$servers->('login','attr','uid');
```

By modifying those two parameters I'm able to login as "eric" / "password"

However, when I try to authenticate as

```
cn=admin,dc=ubuntu,dc=example,dc=com
```

with my rootPW it does not recognize me at all.

Is there another parameter the `config.php` file that I would need to change in order to be able to use both DN and UID login types? My only way to administrate the test LDAP site right now is to switch back and forth my `config.php` file, which is quite annoying.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like I find the answer to my own question after rebuilding my environment... I'm a brand new network administrator and I've mostly worked with Windows based system so OpenLDAP was a bit confusing but anyways here it goes...

Parameters to modify are the following: (Running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server 32-Bit)

```
$servers->setValue('server','host','XXX.YYY.ZZZ.000');
$servers->setValue('server','base','array('ldap01'));
$servers->setValue('login',''auth_type','session');
$servers->setValue('login','bind_id','cn=admin,dc=ldap01');
$servers->setValue('login','bind_pass','Z00lOO');
$servers->setValue('login','attr','uid');
$servers->setValue('login','fallback_dn','true);
```

Comment: if you could give a 'before' and 'after' comparing the two, this would be a *really* helpful answer. +1 all the same (good work!)